# how to work d3 with json format instead of csv?

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

i am trying to popurlate my data from json to d3 visual.
i had a json result returning me Date and count.

how to replace this function with json?
original link [Got my sample of d3 from here](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/34f08d5e11952a80609169b7917d4172)

```
 d3.csv('@Server.MapPath("Views/file/sp500.csv")', type, function (error, data) {
```

**Json file**

```
[{Month: "February 2014", Count: 50}, {Month: "March 2014", Count: 66},…]
```

currently with this it did fire the json but there is an error saying `cannot read the property of null`

```
d3.json("/JuraServicing/GetStatistic", function (data) {
```

Comment: Did you modify your version of the code to refer to `Month` and `Count` properties instead of `date` and `price` in the example data?

Comment: Hi, Yea i did modified and change all the variable accordingly to the json column

Answer (score 1):

You just need to have double-quoted key values in JSON files. It should work fine then.

This is working fine:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        d3.json("/data.json", function (data) {
                document.write(JSON.stringify(data))
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is data.json

```
[{"Month": "February 2014", "Count": 50}, {"Month": "March 2014", "Count": 6}]
```

Hope it helps!!

Comment: Hi my json was generated from here. so i cant add double quote to the file.`public JsonResult GetStatistic(string year) {
            var machinelist = service.GetAllServicMachine();
                var q = from i in machinelist
                        group i by Convert.ToDateTime(i.receive_datum).ToString("MMM yyyy") into grp
                        select new { Count = grp.Count(), Month = grp.Key, };
                return Json(q, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }`

Comment: But then it is not a JSON and it is infact a JavaScript Object which cannot be read by d3.json

Comment: the return result is a json. i tried with other d3 which have json example and i just pass in my url and works fine. This is the sample code given was csv so i convert it to json thinking it will work not.

Comment: Have you tried validating the JSON using JSONLint (https://jsonlint.com/)
Because the JSON you have provided is invalid